# Where I can see the list of the devices connected to my Wi-Fi hotspot on Android 12?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, android-12, google-pixel-6

I use Android 12 + Google Pixel 6.

I can't find the list:

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, stock Android (AOSP) has never integrated such functionality built-in. Unless there's any reference about it somewhere, this is a dupe of an existing question.

Comment: @AndrewT. Got it, thanks!